# About transfer from Hilbert modular forms to Siegel modular forms

Tags: nt.number-theory, automorphic-forms

Suppose $F$ is a totally real field of degree $d$. Is there an explicit way (like theta series or so) to construct automorphic forms on $\mathrm{Gsp}(2d)$ from Hilbert modular forms of ${\rm GL}_2(F)$?

Comment: Hey, I wasn't sure whether it is $G_{sp}$ or ${\rm Gsp}$.

Comment: For real quadratic and some definition of explicit see https://arxiv.org/pdf/1006.5105.pdf. But i take it you want Fourier-Siegel coefficients and not just eigenvalues.

Comment: A seemingly simpler question: Suppose $E$ is a CM field which is a quadratic extension of $F$, and let $\chi$ be a Hecke character of $E$ of appropriate Archimedean type. Then can one associate a CM form for $\mathrm{Gsp}(2d)$ to $\chi$ in an explicit way?